# Angular shared modules and webpack

Tags: angular, webpack-2, es6-modules

We are trying to figure out what is the correct approach for sharing modules in Angular with Webpack.

We have components that are re-used in various locations of our application. They are not used in all views of the application but most.

We created a sharedModule that imports and exports the components. This sharedModule is then imported in the needed areas of the application.

This is where we start to wonder. If module A imports sharedModule but only needs 2 of the 5 shared components, what happens to the 3 imported components not needed?

We understand that Webpack is supposed to do tree shaking and deadcode removal, but do we want to rely on Webpack to do this, or do we not use a sharedModule and import the components where we need them only?

Answer (score 0):

if you load shared module in app.module it will load all components and directives even if the page don't need them.

i suggest you to split the shared module, and keep there only the components and directives that you need across your application.

for example, if you have 3 components that you need in only 3 pages, create a module that holds only those 3 and export them from that module.

it will increase your performance dramatically if your shared module is pretty big right now.

split as much as you can to small modules.